# substr values don't match preg_match_all PREG_PATTERN_ORDER

Tags: php, preg-match-all, substr

I've used preg_match_all's `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` to return positions in the values found in a string. Then when trying to `substr`, referencing them back, they don't line up. I expected an offset, but there seems to be an undetermined misalignment per case.

Is this because preg_match_all is returning bytes and not characters? If so, is there a way to convert bytes to characters? If I'm completely off the mark I can post some code...

Okay here is the applicable code:

```
// RETURN POSITION OF START AND END TAGS TO ARRAY
function getTagPositions($strBody, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([\w\s.]*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/im', $strBody, $strTag, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $intOffset = 0;
    $intIndex = 0;
    $intTagPositions = array();

    foreach($strTag[0] as $strFullTag) {
        $intTagPositions[$intIndex] = array('start' => (strpos($strBody, $strFullTag, $intOffset)), 'end' => (strpos($strBody, $strFullTag, $intOffset) + strlen($strFullTag)));
        $intOffset += strlen($strFullTag);
        $intIndex++;
    }
    return $intTagPositions;
}

function arrayValRecursive($key, array $arr){
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);
    });
    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
}

$arrayOfPositions = getTagPositions($html,$go,$stop);
$arrayOfStart = arrayValRecursive('start', $arrayOfPositions);   //print_r($arrayOfStart);
$arrayOfEnd = arrayValRecursive('end', $arrayOfPositions);   //print_r($arrayOfEnd);

  $offset = 0;
  $range = $arrayOfStart[$i] + $offset;
  $rangeEnd = $arrayOfEnd[$i];    
  echo '<br>'.$range.' to '.$rangeEnd.' is: <br>'; 
  echo substr($html, $range, $rangeEnd);
```

Comment: [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) "Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred." Looks like you use this function incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

> **Return Values**
>   Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

If you want to get offsets into the string, use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`

> **PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE**
>   If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of matches into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset 0 and its string offset into subject at offset 1.

Here's an example:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\S+/', 'Hello, world!', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo "count=$count\n";
var_dump($matches);
```

This gives as output

```
count=2
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Hello,"
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "world!"
      [1]=>
      int(7)
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the pattern matches `$count=2` times. It matches "Hello," at position `$matches[0][0][1]=0` and it matches "world!" at position `$matches[0][1][1]=7`

And here's how you loop through all matches

```
$start = array();
$end = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $start[] = $match[1];
    $end[] = $match[1] + strlen($match[0]);
}
```

Comment: I found the getTagPositions function on php.net after looking for a solution using `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`. Could you please demonstrate how to use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` within this function instead? Thanks.

Comment: @John See the updated answer. This should give you an idea how the `$matches` are structured with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Thanks for that. so far I have this:          `function arrayPositions($string, $start, $end){
$count = preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([\w\s.]*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/im', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
//echo "count=$count\n";
//var_dump($matches);
}`          how do I get an array of all the 'start' values and another of the 'end' values. By incorporating your example into the function it breaks the arrayValRecursive function.

Comment: @John The start values are already there, as I wrote in the example. And for the end offsets, you can take the start offsets and add the length of matches: `$start = $matches[0][0][1]; $end = $start + strlen($matches[0][0][0]);`

Comment: It seems to return a single integer as apposed to an array of integers. Does it need a foreach loop? Here's what I have:CODE>>   `function arrayPositions($string, $start, $end){
$count = preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([\w\s.]*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/im', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
//echo "count=$count\n";
//var_dump($matches);
$start = array();
$end = array();
$start = $matches[0][0][1];

$end = $start + strlen($matches[0][0][0]);
print_r($start);
echo '<hr>';
print_r($end);
}`

Comment: @John Yes, this was for the first one only. Look at the end of my answer. I added, how you get all start and end offsets.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf! This one had me stumped for a long time.